# Question of trust in hyperledger fabric for chaincode instantiator

Tags: security, hyperledger-fabric

Must the chaincode creator be trusted by whole network? From my understanding chaincodes are installed and instantiated by some authorized user. And if my understanding is correct they are distributed in binary form.

Let's assume that we have **OrgA** and **OrgB** each of them having one peer and endorsing policy requires both of them to sign the transaction proposal.

- Peer.OrgA
- Peer.OrgB

Let's assume that  OrgA is instantiating chaincode in the channel. Is there any way for OrgB to validate its logic?

I understand that due to endorsement process and read-write sets we are protected on blockchain level against double spending.

But what about business level? What if chaincode is doing some tricky manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

For chaincode instantiation and installation you can stablish policies on who can do it. Also for a chaincode to be instantiated it is needed to create packages that in order to be instantiated and installed need to be signed by all the participants of the network, or whatever policy that you have. You can read more about it here.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/chaincode4noah.html

This packages can be reviewed by the organizations.

Comment: Thank you! I will review the doc. If every organization must sign the chaincode in its source code form then it would solve the issue